# Differential Equation Find general solution of y'' - y =cosh(x) using variation of parameters

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hello I am having some issues with the simplification of the DE, I am okay up on till $$y_p(x)=v_1(x)y_{p1}(x) + v_2(x)y_{p2}(x) $$

$$ \frac12 e^{-x}\left(\frac {-e^{2x}}4-\frac x2\right)+ \frac 12e^{x}\left(\frac {-e^{-2x}}4+\frac x2\right)$$
I cannot simplify it to get $\frac x2 \sinh(x)$ I would appreciate some clarification if possible

Comment: i see the $$ \frac x2 sinh(x)$$ but what about the $$ \frac 14*cosh(x)$$

Comment: okay i think i understand, is it due to the fact that i have terms in the $y_p(x)$ that are repeated in the homogeneous part and they are not unique so i can ignore them in the final general solution?

Comment: Expand, simplify and regroup.

Comment: This could be simpler if you took $\cosh(x)$ and $\sinh(x)$ as the basis solution of the homogeneous system.

Answer (score 1):

The simplification is tricky if you aren't looking for it. You get rid of the $\tfrac14\cosh(x)$ when you combine the complementary solution with the particular solution.

Simplification from where you are:

- Group like terms:: $$\tfrac14x(e^x - e^{-x}) - \tfrac18(e^x + e^{-x})$$
- This simplifies to:: $$\tfrac12x\sinh(x) - \tfrac18(e^x + e^{-x})$$
  You don't want to simplify the last term into $-\tfrac14\cosh(x)$ because of the following:
  $$
  Y = Y_c + Y_p.
  \\
    Y = (A)e^{-x} + (B)e^x - \tfrac18(e^x + e^{-x}) + \tfrac12x\sinh(x).
  \\
  (A - \tfrac18)e^{-x} = Ce^{-x}\\ (B - \tfrac18)e^x = De^{x}.
  $$
  The arbitrary constant from the complimentary solution combined with the $-\tfrac18$ from the particular solution can be simplified as another arbitrary constant.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Comment: In short: we have quite good latex support, enter `$\frac{1}{4}$` and you will get $\frac{1}{4}$. Please edit your question to make your formulas better comprehensible. I started it and added some formatting.